# big blue button server behind NAT Error 1002

Tags: nat, wss, bigbluebutton

I have a dedicated server that i want to install big blue button (bbb) on it. The server is behind a NAT and its IP in the network is 192.168.10.203 and i have vc.tagsoo.ir subdomain that points to a static IP 46.249.123.202 which is my network. In the microtic i forwarded TCP ports 80, 443, 7443 and UDP 16384-32768 to the internal server. I installed exactly Ubuntu 16.04 and checked the firewall to see if i can access the ports or not. I used bbb-install.sh like below to install bbb:

```
wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v xenial-22 -s vc.tagsoo.ir -e info@tagsoo.ir -w -x -g
```

It installs successfully and in the network every thing works including webcam and microphone but from outside webcam and microphone doesn't work. so i followed extra steps when server is behind NAT. I added stun server 173.194.219.127:19302 and now webcam is working from anywhere. I continued all steps and replaced external IP all places that mentioned in the help. Now I can join an audio session but for microphone (in the network or from outside) i got error 1002. I also added a dummy NIC but it didn't help. freeswitch is running:

```
● freeswitch.service - freeswitch
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/freeswitch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-09-05 18:17:43 +0430; 4min 50s ago
  Process: 33240 ExecStart=/opt/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -u freeswitch -g daemon -ncwait $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 33262 (freeswitch)
    Tasks: 37
   Memory: 34.7M
      CPU: 3.092s
   CGroup: /system.slice/freeswitch.service
           └─33262 /opt/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch -u freeswitch -g daemon -ncwait -nonat

Sep 05 18:17:41 tagbbb systemd[1]: Starting freeswitch...
Sep 05 18:17:41 tagbbb freeswitch[33240]: 33262 Backgrounding.
Sep 05 18:17:43 tagbbb systemd[1]: Started freeswitch.
```

I even changed the wss-binding to point to external point but it didn't work. Here is the bbb-conf --check result:

```
BigBlueButton Server 2.2.23 (2106)
                    Kernel version: 4.4.0-187-generic
                      Distribution: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (64-bit)
                            Memory: 32903 MB
                         CPU cores: 20

/usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties (bbb-web)
       bigbluebutton.web.serverURL: https://vc.tagsoo.ir
                defaultGuestPolicy: ALWAYS_ACCEPT
                 svgImagesRequired: true

/etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton (nginx)
                       server name: vc.tagsoo.ir
                              port: 80, [::]:80
                              port: 443 ssl
                    bbb-client dir: /var/www/bigbluebutton

/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml (bbb-client)
                Port test (tunnel): rtmp://vc.tagsoo.ir
                              red5: vc.tagsoo.ir
              useWebrtcIfAvailable: true

/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/vars.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                       local_ip_v4: 192.168.10.203
                   external_rtp_ip: 46.249.123.202
                   external_sip_ip: 46.249.123.202

/opt/freeswitch/etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles/external.xml (FreeSWITCH)
                        ext-rtp-ip: $${external_rtp_ip}
                        ext-sip-ip: $${external_sip_ip}
                        ws-binding: :5066
                       wss-binding: 192.168.10.203:7443

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/core/scripts/bigbluebutton.yml (record and playback)
                     playback_host: vc.tagsoo.ir
                 playback_protocol: https
                            ffmpeg: 4.2.2-1bbb1~ubuntu16.04

/etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx (sip.nginx)
                        proxy_pass: 46.249.123.202

/usr/local/bigbluebutton/bbb-webrtc-sfu/config/default.yml (Kurento SFU)
                        kurento.ip: 192.168.10.203
                       kurento.url: ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
                    kurento.sip_ip: 192.168.10.203
                    localIpAddress: 192.168.10.203
               recordScreenSharing: true
                     recordWebcams: true
                  codec_video_main: VP8
               codec_video_content: VP8

/usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/settings.yml (HTML5 client)
                             build: 1006
                        kurentoUrl: wss://vc.tagsoo.ir/bbb-webrtc-sfu
                  enableListenOnly: true


# Potential problems described below
# IP does not match:
#                           IP from ifconfig: 192.168.10.203
#   /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton: vc.tagsoo.ir

# Warning: The setting of 46.249.123.202 for proxy_pass in
#
#    /etc/bigbluebutton/nginx/sip.nginx
#
# does not match the local IP address (192.168.10.203).
# (This is OK if you've manually changed the values)
```

I don't know what to do else. It's more than one week i'm trying.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the question i installed bbb using bbb-install.sh, i didn't find any answer for my problem and for the last time i run the command again and followed extra steps when server is behind NAT for the last time and everything works now. Actually i totally run the install command 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

your ws-binding: :5066 is not include public external ip address. you should add your external sip ip address there.Also wss-binding is inculuding internal ip. you should change it with external too. Then restrat bbb. it will work.